TCP SEQ or ACK do not increment despite non-zero LEN
My TCP downloads (git fetch, Chrome browser downloads, flatpak downloads) often fail to complete. When I look into the packets with Wireshark, I find that the connection ends in RST from the client.
Prior to the RST, however, the SEQ of the RST is repeated many times in both client and server ACKs and PSHs in the SEQ and ACK fields, even if LEN is non-zero. In the example below, SEQ/ACK == 1517 first appears at 2.87 s, and it repeats about 10,000 times until 3.77 s at which the first RST is sent.


This issue is replicated for different clients (my devices), servers (where I download from), and connectors (ethernet cables and ports). The only constant is the router, which is largely outside of my control. To begin to access the router settings, I need to have a good idea of what the problem might be. What could be causing these consistent download failures?
